# Are real foci of an algebraic curve contained in a disk also inside this disk?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, polynomials

Let $\Gamma$ be a plane real algebraic curve whose (non-empty) set of real points on the plane is contained in the disk $x^2+y^2<1$. More precisely, we have a homogeneous polynomial $F(x,y,z)$ with real coefficients, and $\Gamma$ is given in the projective plane $\mathbb P^2(\mathbb C)$ by the equation $F=0$. We assume that the real points $(x,y,z)$ that are solutions of this equation satisfy $x^2 + y^2 < z^2$.

The question is: is it true that all its real foci are also inside this disk?

I am using Plücker's definition of the real foci: points at which lines through the circular points $(1,\pm i, 0)\in \mathbb P^2(\mathbb C)$ are tangent to $\Gamma$.

Sorry if this question is trivial or naive, my knowledge of algebraic geometry is limited.

Comment: There are trivial counterexamples where $\Gamma(\mathbb{R})$ is empty, e.g. $F(x,y,z)=(x-2z)^2+y^2+z^2$ with real focus $(2:0:0)$.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly of course you are right, I should have mentioned the assumption that $\Gamma(\mathbb R)$ is not empty. Do you have any counterexample for this case?

Comment: Well, clearly you can take the union of "my" curve and a "normal" one, e.g. $F(x,y,z)=[(−2)^2+^2+^2](2x^2+2y^2-z^2)$.

Comment: Yes, @LaurentMoret-Bailly, I guess you are right! That was helpful, thank you.